# herabfallen vs abfallen vs fallen

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

The perfect participle form of these three all mean "fallen", but I want to know if they have any semantic differences? If so, then how would a simple sentence like he is fallen from ... "Er ist herabgefallen/.../... von ..." be interpreted differently or in some aspect more specifically? like where the direction of the fall is from and is heading.

I found herabgefallen from the book Bahnwaerter Thiel. It is from this sentence: "Im Verlaufe von zehn Jahren, war er zweimal krank gewesen; das einer Mal infolge eines vom Tender einer Maschine waehrend des Vorbeifahrens herabgefallenen Stueckes Kohle, ..." For ten years, he was only sick twice; one time because of a piece of coal fallen from a passing tender car of an engine, ...

Comment: These are the perfect participles of the verbs *herabfallen*, *abfallen* and *fallen*. It makes no sense the discuss the meanings of the participles. Look up the verbs in a dictionary before asking about them here.

Comment: Although I think that the meaning of the infinitives was implied in the question, why do you think it does not make sense to discuss the meaning of participles?

Comment: I can't believe that I have to explain that the meanings of the participles are derived from the infinitive in a straightforward manner. It's the infinitives which are listed in a dictionary, and if one looks up the infinitives in a good dictionary one can see that their respective meanings differ.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please take note of the hint from Rha and consider rewriting your question with the infinitives.

Comment: There is no good dictionary I could find on the internet that would give their different meanings in neither inf. or par. form. I made this post in the middle of the night as well as creating this account. I read it in the par. form in the book and I intended to use it in par. form as well, so I didn't take the time to consider asking it in their inf. form. It made sense to me at the time and I'm sorry it didn't make sense to you. I will change them to inf. form nonetheless. @RHa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if they have any semantic differences?

Yes they have. Your words are the past form, let's look at the present.

- herabfallen (or herunterfallen, runterfallen) = to fall **down** with focus on down, although I have no plausible idea where else it could fall from :-)
- abfallen = to fall **off**
- fallen = to fall (in general)

An object that is *abgefallen* has fallen off from something, that means it was connected to something and now got loose and gravity took its chance to move it away. No long way is implied to fall, it could just have loosened and now is 1 mm below its original place.

The object that has *abgefallen* (has loosened) can now *herabfallen* (fall down) because it's no longer held in place.
For the piece of coal the word *abfallen* can not really be used because it actually was somewhere above on the coal wagon but not fixed to other coal or the wagon.

*fallen* in general is to fall in any variation. The piece of coal falls ... it's moving downward without anything said about why and where from.
*fallen* is also used in context of a person or animal that stumbles and now drops down.
*How did you break your leg? Ich bin gestolpert und gefallen.*
In everyday's language one would say *hingefallen*.

Comment: *somewhere above on the coal wagon but not fixed to other coal or the wagon* --- Since it is a **tender** wagon with a **heap** of coal, I think *fall down off from* is OK. Like snow, down from off a roof. *Der ganze Schnee is vom Dach herabgefallen*. (Well, herabgerutscht). Herabgefallen explains exactly how it happened.

Comment: @rastafile Yes you are right with herabfallen, but please note that in the cited phrase I referred to **von ... abfallen**, not **von .. herabfallen**. Perhaps my usage of **falling off (from)** was not the best choice. I wanted to bring out that in German **ab**fallen is used for something that was fixed/mounted and isn't any more.

Comment: when things fall down from a higher level in respect to my position, it is "**herabfallen, herunterfallen**". When stuff falls down to a lower level it is "**hinabfallen, hinunterfallen**".

Answer (score 2):

To add to [puck's](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56618/41312) answer:

`herabfallen` is sometimes used metaphorically. Examples given in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herabfallen) are:

- "die Sonnenstrahlen **fielen** auf ihr helles Haar **herab**"
- "Finsternis, Nacht **fällt** auf die Stadt **herab**"

Which means

- "Sunshine fell down on her hair"
- "Darkness, the night falls down on the city"

respectively.

Could also be used with only using `fallen` I guess, but `herabfallen` sounds older and might even sound off to some.

Comment: to enrich your answer with figurativly use, you might add sth like: "die Last fällt von mir ab" / "das fällt von meinen Schultern (ab)".